# Redirect CMD to a text file. (OR globally increase history)

Tags: windows, cmd.exe

Hello some other application is constantly crashing upon loading. It gives "neatly" a long (java) exception with stack trace. However this exception is so long that it pushes the actual exception directly out of the history of the cmd.

Is there a way to "catch" this full exception test?

Answer (score 1):

By using the "greater than" symbol, you can redirect the output of a command to any file that you'd like.

```
C:\Users\Foo>bar.exe > error.txt
```

This redirects standard output.  Java stack trace is by convention sent to standard *error* not to standard *output*, though.  So you have to redirect standard error to the same place

```
C:\Users\Foo>bar.exe > error.txt 2>&1
```

Or, if you don't want standard output to go to that file, redirect standard error alone

```
C:\Users\Foo>bar.exe 2> error.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

## Adjust the screen buffer size

1. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> or right-click the command prompt title bar.
2. Choose **Defaults** from the menu.
3. Click the **Layout** tab.
4. Under **Screen Buffer Size**, increase the **Height** value (default is `300`).
5. Click **OK** to apply the changes.
6. If the increased buffer is not big enough to hold the whole text, increase it again.